# Add condition on contact form 7 auto response

Tags: email, conditional-statements, response, contact-form-7, auto

i want to set if anyone select EV Car Solutions then the auto response will work. but somehow the code isn't working.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' );

function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {
    // The contact form ID.
    if ( 371 === $contact_form->id ) {
        $submission  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        // Dropdowns are stored as arrays.
        if ( isset( $posted_data['menu-175'] ) && $posted_data['menu-175'][0] === 'EV Car Solutions' ) {
            $msg = 'Thank you for selecting EV Car Solutions. We will get back to you shortly.';
            // mail it to them using wp_mail.
            wp_mail( $posted_data['your-email'], 'Auto-response for EV car charger selection', $msg );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to explain what isn't working here, since the code by itself would work, if all of the form fields you list are shown.  What is your email field name in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not being executed as the `id` property of the WPCF7_ContactForm class is private and can only be accessed with its method `id()`.  Try instead,

```php
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' );

function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {
    // The contact form ID.
    if ( 371 === $contact_form->id() ) {
        $submission  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        // Dropdowns are stored as arrays.
        if ( isset( $posted_data['menu-175'] ) && $posted_data['menu-175'][0] === 'EV Car Solutions' ) {
            $msg = 'Thank you for selecting EV Car Solutions. We will get back to you shortly.';
            // mail it to them using wp_mail.
            wp_mail( $posted_data['your-email'], 'Auto-response for EV car charger selection', $msg );
        }
    }
}
```